# Fastest way to make division between a number and elements in a list

Tags: syntax, map

I have a list y={{a,b},{c,d},...} of dimension {10^5, 2}, and number x. I want to divide only the second part of each element of the list by x, and have as result a new list
{{a,b/x},{c,d/x},...}. What is the fastest/best way to do it? This is what I have done:

```
{#[[1]], Divide[#[[2]], x]} & /@y
```

Thanks

Comment: List[[All,2]]=list[[All,2]]/x

Comment: `y[[All, 2]] /= x; y`

Comment: Why are answers given as comments?

Comment: @Philipp I was looking for a duplicate :)

Answer (score 2):

If `y` is a packed array then `Dot` should be quite fast:

```
y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^5, 2}];
x = 12.3;

result = y.{{1, 0}, {0, 1/x}};
```

This takes about a millisecond on my not-very-fast PC.